# Record Consecutive Days by Group in R

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
DATE <- as.Date(c('2016-12-01', '2016-12-02', '2016-12-03', '2016-12-04', '2016-12-01', '2016-12-03', '2016-12-04', '2016-12-04' ))
Parent <- c('A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B')
Child <- c('ab', 'ab', 'ab', 'ab', 'ac','ac', 'ac','bd')
salary <- c(1000, 100, 4000, 2000,1000,3455,1234,600)
avg_child_salary <- c(500, 500, 500, 500, 300, 300, 300, 9000)
Callout <- c('HIGH', 'LOW', 'HIGH', 'HIGH', 'HIGH', 'HIGH', 'HIGH', 'LOW')
employ.data <- data.frame(DATE, Parent, Child, avg_child_salary, salary, Callout)

employ.data

        DATE Parent Child avg_child_salary salary Callout
1 2016-12-01      A    ab              500   1000    HIGH
2 2016-12-02      A    ab              500    100     LOW
3 2016-12-03      A    ab              500   4000    HIGH
4 2016-12-04      A    ab              500   2000    HIGH
5 2016-12-01      A    ac              300   1000    HIGH
6 2016-12-03      A    ac              300   3455    HIGH
7 2016-12-04      A    ac              300   1234    HIGH
8 2016-12-04      B    bd             9000    600     LOW
```

I have filtered out just yesterday's data being `2016-12-04` as follows:

```
yesterday <- as.Date(Sys.Date()-1)
df2<-filter(employ.data, DATE == yesterday)
df2

            DATE Parent Child avg_child_salary salary Callout
    4 2016-12-04      A    ab              500   2000    HIGH
    7 2016-12-04      A    ac              300   1234    HIGH
    8 2016-12-04      B    bd             9000    600     LOW
```

My goal is to include a column next to `Callout` showing the amount of consecutive days from `2016-12-04` the callout has been `HIGH` or `LOW` by `Child` based on the `employ.data` dataframe. This is what I need as the final output:

```
            DATE Parent Child avg_child_salary salary Callout   Consec. Days with Callout
    4 2016-12-04      A    ab              500   2000    HIGH                           2
    7 2016-12-04      A    ac              300   1234    HIGH                           2
    8 2016-12-04      B    bd             9000    600     LOW                           1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach that is quite messy but I think does what you want:

```
library(dplyr)
yesterday <- as.Date(Sys.Date()-1)
df2 <- employ.data %>% group_by(Child) %>%
  mutate(`Consec. Days with Callout`=cumsum(rev(cumprod(rev((yesterday-DATE)==(which(DATE == yesterday)-row_number()) & Callout==Callout[DATE == yesterday]))))) %>%
  filter(DATE == yesterday)
##Source: local data frame [3 x 7]
##Groups: Child [3]
##
##        DATE Parent  Child avg_child_salary salary Callout Consec. Days with Callout
##      <date> <fctr> <fctr>            <dbl>  <dbl>  <fctr>                     <dbl>
##1 2016-12-04      A     ab              500   2000    HIGH                         2
##2 2016-12-04      A     ac              300   1234    HIGH                         2
##3 2016-12-04      B     bd             9000    600     LOW                         1
```

Notes:

1. `(yesterday-DATE)==(which(DATE == yesterday)-row_number()) & Callout==Callout[DATE == yesterday]` computes a condition that will be `TRUE` for the row if the `Callout` is the same as the `Callout` for `yesterday` and if the distance in rows from the row that is `yesterday` is the same as the distance in days for the date. This gives the `Cond` column as shown below:

   ```
   Source: local data frame [8 x 7]
   Groups: Child [3]

           DATE Parent  Child avg_child_salary salary Callout  Cond
         <date> <fctr> <fctr>            <dbl>  <dbl>  <fctr> <lgl>
   1 2016-12-01      A     ab              500   1000    HIGH  TRUE
   2 2016-12-02      A     ab              500    100     LOW FALSE
   3 2016-12-03      A     ab              500   4000    HIGH  TRUE
   4 2016-12-04      A     ab              500   2000    HIGH  TRUE
   5 2016-12-01      A     ac              300   1000    HIGH FALSE
   6 2016-12-03      A     ac              300   3455    HIGH  TRUE
   7 2016-12-04      A     ac              300   1234    HIGH  TRUE
   8 2016-12-04      B     bd             9000    600     LOW  TRUE
   ```
2. Given this we want to count backwards the number of consecutive `TRUE` from the row that is `yesterday` (grouped by `Child`). To do this, we can reverse the vector using `rev`, do a `cumprod`, which will switch from `1` to `0` as soon as it encounters a `FALSE`, reverse the vector back again using `rev`, and finally do the `cumsum` to accumulate the consecutive days. Doing this gives the following where the `Consec. Days with Callout` column is interpreted as the number of previous consecutive days with the same `Callout` as `yesterday`:

   ```
   Source: local data frame [8 x 7]
   Groups: Child [3]

           DATE Parent  Child avg_child_salary salary Callout Consec. Days with Callout
         <date> <fctr> <fctr>            <dbl>  <dbl>  <fctr>                     <dbl>
   1 2016-12-01      A     ab              500   1000    HIGH                         0
   2 2016-12-02      A     ab              500    100     LOW                         0
   3 2016-12-03      A     ab              500   4000    HIGH                         1
   4 2016-12-04      A     ab              500   2000    HIGH                         2
   5 2016-12-01      A     ac              300   1000    HIGH                         0
   6 2016-12-03      A     ac              300   3455    HIGH                         1
   7 2016-12-04      A     ac              300   1234    HIGH                         2
   8 2016-12-04      B     bd             9000    600     LOW                         1
   ```
3. Finally, do the `filter` as you did to generate the final result.

Comment: Are you having problems with this answer? If so, please leave comment here. Otherwise, I won't receive them directly.

Comment: I believe you are getting that error because you have a group for which there are no date that matches `yesterday`. Is that true?

Answer (score 2):

try this my man

```
library(lubridate)

df3 <- df2 %>% 
       group_by(child, callout) %>%                          
       mutate(DATE = ymd(DATE), 
              consecutive_day_flag = if_else(DATE == (lag(DATE) + days(1)), 1, 0),
              how_many = sum(consecutive_day_flag))
```

Comment: this is really good thank you. The only thing is that the Consec. Days with Callout is off from the numbers I have on top. I'm guessing it has to do with not including 2016-12-04 as 1 day already. It has to reference the employ.data dataframe. Let me know if this makes sense and thanks for your help!

Comment: I apologize for not making it clear in the question, just revised the question. @Noobie

Comment: by consecutive you mean only days where the next day is the previous + one? say a saturday follows the friday or a monday follows the Friday? Or maybe do you only care about the number of unique days?

Comment: Meaning a Saturday following a Friday is a consecutive day but Sunday following a Friday is not. So for example, lines 5-7 are all labeled "HIGH" but are not consecutive days because we are skipping 2016-12-02. So the amount of consecutive days for child `ac` should be 2 and not 3.

Comment: So the script needs to refer to the `employ.data` dataframe. Because the consecutive days are based on that. Then I need the amount of consecutive days to be found in `df2`.

Comment: @aichao is there a way to incorporate na.omit into this? I am getting an error saying: Error: incompatible size (0), expecting 1 (the group size) or 1 in my actual dataset

Comment: @aichao, any idea why I am getting this error? `Error: incompatible size (0), expecting 1 (the group size) or 1` ?