# Consecutive Days by Group - Error in Mutate Function Dplyr

Tags: r, join, dplyr

This is a continuation from the question: [Record Consecutive Days by Group in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40983647/record-consecutive-days-by-group-in-r/40984469#40984469)

The answer worked for the dataset in the example I posted but I realized there was something wrong with my actual dataset and an error came up stating: `Error: incompatible size (0), expecting 1 (the group size) or 1`

Below is the dataset and reproducible example where the error comes up. Anybody know why this is happening?

```
DATE <- as.Date(c('2016-10-26', '2016-10-30', '2016-10-26', '2016-10-20', '2016-10-21', '2016-10-17', '2016-10-26', '2016-10-17', '2016-10-18', '2016-10-20', '2016-10-17', '2016-10-18', '2016-10-17', '2016-10-18', '2016-10-19','2016-10-18', '2016-10-19','2016-10-17','2016-10-17','2016-10-19','2016-10-19','2016-10-20','2016-10-19','2016-10-20','2016-10-30'))
`Parent` <- c('A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G')
Child <- c('ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'ae','af', 'af','ba', 'ba', 'ba', 'ca', 'cb', 'da', 'da', 'da', 'db', 'db', 'ea', 'eb', 'fa', 'ga', 'ga', 'gb', 'gb', 'gb')
salary <- c(290.45, 0.00, 336.51, 2238.56, 2256.75, 725.73, 319.69, 46.48, 42.13, 43.22, 0.41, 865.20, 1889.80, 2691.97, 3016.80, 8636.18, 8540.24, 1587.21, 1416.63, 79.62,1967.95,1947.35,34925.58,31158.51,6973.54)
avg_child_salary <- c(500.29, 526.27, 492.00, 1197.25, 1197.25, 474.10, 474.10, 21.68, 21.68, 21.68, 0.05, 199.90, 575.31, 575.31, 575.31, 1701.82, 1701.82, 495.48, 316.93, 26.16, 582.66, 582.66, 18089.83, 18089.83, 18089.83)
Callout <- c('LOW', 'LOW', 'LOW', 'HIGH', 'HIGH', 'HIGH', 'LOW', 'HIGH', 'HIGH', 'HIGH', 'HIGH', 'HIGH', 'HIGH', 'HIGH', 'HIGH', 'HIGH', 'HIGH', 'HIGH', 'HIGH', 'HIGH', 'HIGH', 'HIGH', 'HIGH', 'HIGH', 'LOW')
employ.data <- data.frame(DATE, Parent, Child, avg_child_salary, salary, Callout)

employ.data

         DATE Parent Child avg_child_salary   salary Callout
1  2016-10-26      A    ab           500.29   290.45     LOW
2  2016-10-30      A    ac           526.27     0.00     LOW
3  2016-10-26      A    ad           492.00   336.51     LOW
4  2016-10-20      A    ae          1197.25  2238.56    HIGH
5  2016-10-21      A    ae          1197.25  2256.75    HIGH
6  2016-10-17      A    af           474.10   725.73    HIGH
7  2016-10-26      A    af           474.10   319.69     LOW
8  2016-10-17      B    ba            21.68    46.48    HIGH
9  2016-10-18      B    ba            21.68    42.13    HIGH
10 2016-10-20      B    ba            21.68    43.22    HIGH
11 2016-10-17      C    ca             0.05     0.41    HIGH
12 2016-10-18      C    cb           199.90   865.20    HIGH
13 2016-10-17      D    da           575.31  1889.80    HIGH
14 2016-10-18      D    da           575.31  2691.97    HIGH
15 2016-10-19      D    da           575.31  3016.80    HIGH
16 2016-10-18      D    db          1701.82  8636.18    HIGH
17 2016-10-19      D    db          1701.82  8540.24    HIGH
18 2016-10-17      E    ea           495.48  1587.21    HIGH
19 2016-10-17      E    eb           316.93  1416.63    HIGH
20 2016-10-19      F    fa            26.16    79.62    HIGH
21 2016-10-19      G    ga           582.66  1967.95    HIGH
22 2016-10-20      G    ga           582.66  1947.35    HIGH
23 2016-10-19      G    gb         18089.83 34925.58    HIGH
24 2016-10-20      G    gb         18089.83 31158.51    HIGH
25 2016-10-30      G    gb         18089.83  6973.54     LOW
```

Then from this dataset I want to gather all the rows containing `2016-10-30` and then in a separate column, count the number of consecutive days with a callout of `LOW` or `HIGH` based on the employ.data dataframe. The number of consecutive days needs to be in a new column next to Callout. This is before applying the errored script:

```
yesterday <- as.Date(Sys.Date()-37)
df2<-filter(employ.data, DATE == yesterday)
df2 

         DATE Parent Child avg_child_salary   salary Callout  
2  2016-10-30      A    ac           526.27     0.00     LOW                          
25 2016-10-30      G    gb         18089.83  6973.54     LOW
```

The code that was attempted is below:

```
library(dplyr)
yesterday <- as.Date(Sys.Date()-37) ##because today is 12/6/16
df2 <- employ.data %>% group_by(Child) %>%
  mutate(`Consec. Days with Callout`=cumsum(rev(cumprod(rev((yesterday-DATE)==(which(DATE == yesterday)-row_number()) & Callout==Callout[DATE == yesterday]))))) %>% filter(DATE == yesterday)
```

In the end it needs to look like this for this particular example:

```
         DATE Parent Child avg_child_salary   salary Callout  Consec. Days with Callout
2  2016-10-30      A    ac           526.27     0.00     LOW                          1
25 2016-10-30      G    gb         18089.83  6973.54     LOW                          1
```

Then the error comes up:

```
Error: incompatible size (0), expecting 1 (the group size) or 1
```

Comment: The issue is that for some groups, the row for `yesterday` is not found. This can be fixed by defining a function that checks for that instead of inlining a function in `mutate`. I will fix this shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that for some groups, the row for `yesterday` is not found. This can be fixed by defining a function that checks for that instead of inlining the function in `mutate`:

```
library(dplyr)
compute.consec.days <- function(date, callout, yesterday, rown) {
  j <- which(date == yesterday)
  if (length(j)==0) NA else cumsum(rev(cumprod(rev((yesterday-date)==(j-rown) & callout==callout[date == yesterday]))))
}
```

This function checks `which` `DATE` is `yesterday`. If not found for the group, then this will return `integer(0)`. We check this by the `length` of the return value `j`. If this is `TRUE`, we return `NA` for the consecutive days, which does not matter since the following `filter` will remove that group (i.e., `yesterday` is not found); otherwise, we compute the consecutive days as before. This avoids the error. Now, with this function and your newly posted data:

```
yesterday <- as.Date("2016-10-30")
out <- employ.data %>% group_by(Child) %>%
  mutate(`Consec. Days with Callout`=compute.consec.days(DATE,Callout,yesterday,row_number())) %>%
  filter(DATE == yesterday)
##Source: local data frame [2 x 7]
##Groups: Child [2]
##
##        DATE Parent  Child avg_child_salary  salary Callout Consec. Days with Callout
##      <date> <fctr> <fctr>            <dbl>   <dbl>  <fctr>                     <dbl>
##1 2016-10-30      A     ac           526.27    0.00     LOW                         1
##2 2016-10-30      G     gb         18089.83 6973.54     LOW                         1
```

---

### Update to support the case where yesterday is not the *last* date in group

If the query for `yesterday` is not the last day for any of the `Child` groups, then we need to modify our `compute.consec.days` function as such:

```
compute.consec.days <- function(date, callout, yesterday, rown) {
  j <- which(date == yesterday)
  if (length(j)==0) NA else {
    ## first compute the condition
    cond <- (yesterday-date)==(j-rown) & callout==callout[date == yesterday]
    ## then evaluate consecutive days only with this vector up to
    ## the row corresponding to yesterday. Then add the result with NAs
    ## because mutate is a windowing function
    c(cumsum(rev(cumprod(rev(cond[1:j[1]])))),rep(NA,length(date)-j[1]))
  }
}
```

For example, if the query for yesterday is `"2016-10-20"` given the newly posted data, then this results in:

```
yesterday <- as.Date("2016-10-20")
out <- employ.data %>% group_by(Child) %>%
  mutate(`Consec. Days with Callout`=compute.consec.days(DATE,Callout,yesterday,row_number())) %>%
  filter(DATE == yesterday)
##Source: local data frame [4 x 7]
##Groups: Child [4]
##
##        DATE Parent  Child avg_child_salary   salary Callout Consec. Days with Callout
##      <date> <fctr> <fctr>            <dbl>    <dbl>  <fctr>                     <dbl>
##1 2016-10-20      A     ae          1197.25  2238.56    HIGH                         1
##2 2016-10-20      B     ba            21.68    43.22    HIGH                         1
##3 2016-10-20      G     ga           582.66  1947.35    HIGH                         2
##4 2016-10-20      G     gb         18089.83 31158.51    HIGH                         2
```

With the original query of `"2016-10-30"`, we still get the original results:

```
yesterday <- as.Date("2016-10-30")
out <- employ.data %>% group_by(Child) %>%
  mutate(`Consec. Days with Callout`=compute.consec.days(DATE,Callout,yesterday,row_number())) %>%
  filter(DATE == yesterday)
##Source: local data frame [2 x 7]
##Groups: Child [2]
##
##        DATE Parent  Child avg_child_salary  salary Callout Consec. Days with Callout
##      <date> <fctr> <fctr>            <dbl>   <dbl>  <fctr>                     <dbl>
##1 2016-10-30      A     ac           526.27    0.00     LOW                         1
##2 2016-10-30      G     gb         18089.83 6973.54     LOW                         1
```

Comment: A hero I am not. I should have anticipated this issue in answering your previous question.

Comment: I extended the function to handle the case where the `yesterday` query is **not** the last `DATE` for a `Child` group. Enjoy!